# How many fingers exist and how did Subaru know the number?

Tags: re-zero

Spoiler alert if you didn't see episodes 9 & 10.

How many fingers exists in Re:ZERO -Starting Life in Another World-?

In episode 23 at 17:50,

> Subaru says that only one is remaining. How did he find out about the number of remaining fingers?

Comment: Looks like he just counted how many they have killed already. And there are supposed to be 10 from the number of hand fingers. Also he could have counted them back when he was captured in that cave when he first met Betelgeuse and his minions.

Comment: @hakase but finger is just a title. It is not rational to decide about a fight based on a guess. Also, back in the cave, he only saw one Betelgeuse. He didn't know that there are more until they killed the first one and they have been attacked by the second one

Comment: Its simple really, Betelgeuse can move from one body to another, the fingers are limitless so long as he has a new body to jump to.

Comment: @ManiEl-darreiny but it is not what he said in the anime. he said only 1 is remaining! how? why?